# A generalization of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $P$ and $P_n$ be probability measures on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with distribution functions $F$ and $F_n$. Moreover, let $F$ be continuous and $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ [weakly converge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) to $P$. Then it holds: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|F_n(x)-F(x)\right|=0\tag{1}$$

*Proof*: Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, w.l.o.g. $A=(a,b]$. Since $F$ is continuous $$P(\partial A)=F(b)-F(b+)=0$$ Thus, by the [portemanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n(A)=P(A)$$

How do I need to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F$ is continuous and $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ weakly converges to $P$, we've got $$\lim F_n(x)=F(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$ Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $$x_k:=\inf\left\{x\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}:F(x)\ge\frac{k}{N}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }k=0,\ldots, N$$ and $$R_n:=\max_{1\le k<N}\left|F_n(x_k)-F(x_k)\right|$$ $(1)\Rightarrow$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=0\tag{2}$$ Let $x\in (x_{k-1},x_k)\Rightarrow$ $$F_n(x)\le F_n(x_k)\le F(x_k)+R_n\le F(x)+\frac{1}{N}+R_n$$ and $F_n(x)\ge F(x)-\frac{1}{N}-R_n$, analogously. Together with $(2)$ we've got $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|F_n(x)-F(x)\right|\le\frac{1}{N}+\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=\frac{1}{N}\to 0\;\;\;\text{for }N\to \infty$$